# iOS - Photos framework - Get only local photos

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, photosframework

I need to retrieve only the local asset from the Photos framework, so only the photos saved locally and not the photos stored into the cloud. How can I achieve this?

UPDATE:

I add more details about the problem as the question has been marked as too broad, even if I don't think it is.

I'm getting the photos using this code :

```
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions.init()
let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(PHAssetMediaType.Image, options: nil)
```

Then, I get a single asset using the `PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageDataForAsset`.

With the fetch I get all the photos from the library, even if they are stored in the cloud. How can I get only local photos, stored on the phone?

Comment: you would look in the `Photos` framework and Also you could check out my github https://github.com/LamourBt/PHAssets_CollectionView  .. I have something that could help you started.

Answer (score 2):

```
PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType(.SmartAlbum, subtype: .SmartAlbumUserLibrary, options: nil)
```